# How to normalize a histogram in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, histogram, normalization

How to normalize a histogram such that the area under the probability density function is equal to 1?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

My answer to this is the same as in an answer to your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303372/uniform-distribution-u0-1-normal-distribution-nmean-variance2-n-in-matla). For a probability density function, [the integral over the entire space is 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function). Dividing by the sum will **not** give you the correct density. To get the right density, you must divide by the area. To illustrate my point, try the following example.

```
[f, x] = hist(randn(10000, 1), 50); % Create histogram from a normal distribution.
g = 1 / sqrt(2 * pi) * exp(-0.5 * x .^ 2); % pdf of the normal distribution

% METHOD 1: DIVIDE BY SUM
figure(1)
bar(x, f / sum(f)); hold on
plot(x, g, 'r'); hold off

% METHOD 2: DIVIDE BY AREA
figure(2)
bar(x, f / trapz(x, f)); hold on
plot(x, g, 'r'); hold off
```

You can see for yourself which method agrees with the correct answer (red curve).

[image]

Another method (more straightforward than method 2) to normalize the histogram is to divide by `sum(f * dx)` which expresses the integral of the probability density function, i.e.

```
% METHOD 3: DIVIDE BY AREA USING sum()
figure(3)
dx = diff(x(1:2))
bar(x, f / sum(f * dx)); hold on
plot(x, g, 'r'); hold off
```

Comment: The sum of the "Divide by area figure" doesn't equal 1. I see at least 10 bar plot points greater than 0.3. 0.3*10 = 3.0 Wouldn't a simpler solution be to divide f by the # of samples? In this case, 10000.

Comment: @Rich The bars are thinner than 1, so your calculation is wrong.

Consider the triangle unter the curve from (-2,0) to (0, 0.4) to (2, 0) to estimate the area. This triangle has an area of 0.5*4*0.4 = 0.8 < 1.0

Comment: to get the sum equal to 1, you need to multiply the new sum of bins by the width of the bin

Comment: @abcd: But this article says, we can divide by the sum for normalizing: http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/histogra.htm

Comment: How to do this using histcounts instead of hist?

Answer (score 24):

Since 2014b, Matlab has these **normalization routines embedded natively** in the `histogram` function (see the [help file](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html) for the 6 routines this function offers). Here is an example using the **PDF normalization** (the sum of all the bins is 1).

```
data = 2*randn(5000,1) + 5;             % generate normal random (m=5, std=2)
h = histogram(data,'Normalization','pdf')   % PDF normalization
```

The corresponding PDF is

```
Nbins = h.NumBins;
edges = h.BinEdges; 
x = zeros(1,Nbins);
for counter=1:Nbins
    midPointShift = abs(edges(counter)-edges(counter+1))/2;
    x(counter) = edges(counter)+midPointShift;
end

mu = mean(data);
sigma = std(data);

f = exp(-(x-mu).^2./(2*sigma^2))./(sigma*sqrt(2*pi));
```

The two together gives

```
hold on;
plot(x,f,'LineWidth',1.5)
```

[image]

*An improvement that might very well be due to the success of the actual question and accepted answer!*

---

EDIT - The use of `hist` and `histc` is [not recommended](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) now, and `histogram` should be used instead. Beware that none of the 6 ways of creating bins with this new function will produce the bins  `hist` and `histc` produce. There is a Matlab script to update former code to fit the way  `histogram` is called (bin edges instead of bin centers - [link](https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/4366-convert-bin-centers-to-bin-edges)). By doing so, one can **compare the `pdf` normalization methods** of @abcd (`trapz` and `sum`) and Matlab (`pdf`).

**The 3 `pdf` normalization method give nearly identical results (within the range of `eps`)**.

TEST:

```
A = randn(10000,1);
centers = -6:0.5:6;
d = diff(centers)/2;
edges = [centers(1)-d(1), centers(1:end-1)+d, centers(end)+d(end)];
edges(2:end) = edges(2:end)+eps(edges(2:end));

figure;
subplot(2,2,1);
hist(A,centers);
title('HIST not normalized');

subplot(2,2,2);
h = histogram(A,edges);
title('HISTOGRAM not normalized');

subplot(2,2,3)
[counts, centers] = hist(A,centers); %get the count with hist
bar(centers,counts/trapz(centers,counts))
title('HIST with PDF normalization');


subplot(2,2,4)
h = histogram(A,edges,'Normalization','pdf')
title('HISTOGRAM with PDF normalization');

dx = diff(centers(1:2))
normalization_difference_trapz = abs(counts/trapz(centers,counts) - h.Values);
normalization_difference_sum = abs(counts/sum(counts*dx) - h.Values);

max(normalization_difference_trapz)
max(normalization_difference_sum)
```

[image]

The maximum difference between the new PDF normalization and the former one is 5.5511e-17.

Comment: The area under PDFs is not one in your histograms, which is impossible in probability theory. See the answer stackoverflow.com/a/38813376/54964 where some corrections. To match the area one under `pdf`, you should have the normalization set as `probability`, not `pdf`.

Answer (score 11):

`hist` can not only plot an histogram but also return you the count of elements in each bin, so you can get that count, normalize it by dividing each bin by the total and plotting the result using `bar`. Example:

```
Y = rand(10,1);
C = hist(Y);
C = C ./ sum(C);
bar(C)
```

or if you want a one-liner:

```
bar(hist(Y) ./ sum(hist(Y)))
```

### Documentation:

- [hist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hist.html)
- [bar](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bar.html)

*Edit:* This solution answers the question *How to have the sum of all bins equal to 1*. This approximation is valid only if your bin size is small relative to the variance of your data. The sum used here correspond to a simple quadrature formula, more complex ones can be used like `trapz` as proposed by *R. M.*

Answer (score 5):

```
[f,x]=hist(data)
```

The area for each individual bar is height*width. Since MATLAB will choose equidistant points for the bars, so the width is:

```
delta_x = x(2) - x(1)
```

Now if we sum up all the individual bars the total area will come out as

```
A=sum(f)*delta_x
```

So the correctly scaled plot is obtained by

```
bar(x, f/sum(f)/(x(2)-x(1)))
```

Answer (score 3):

The area of abcd`s PDF is not one, which is impossible like pointed out in many comments. 
Assumptions done in many answers here

1. Assume constant distance between consecutive edges.
2. Probability under `pdf` should be 1. The normalization should be done as `Normalization` with `probability`, not as `Normalization` with `pdf`, in histogram() and hist().

Fig. 1 Output of hist() approach, Fig. 2 Output of histogram() approach

[image]
[image]

The max amplitude differs between two approaches which proposes that there are some mistake in hist()'s approach because histogram()'s approach uses the standard normalization. 
I assume the mistake with hist()'s approach here is about the normalization as partially `pdf`, not completely as `probability`.

### Code with hist() [deprecated]

Some remarks

1. First check: `sum(f)/N` gives `1` if `Nbins` manually set.
2. pdf requires the width of the bin (`dx`) in the graph `g`

Code

```
%http://stackoverflow.com/a/5321546/54964
N=10000;
Nbins=50;
[f,x]=hist(randn(N,1),Nbins); % create histogram from ND

%METHOD 4: Count Densities, not Sums!
figure(3)
dx=diff(x(1:2)); % width of bin
g=1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-0.5*x.^2) .* dx; % pdf of ND with dx
% 1.0000
bar(x, f/sum(f));hold on
plot(x,g,'r');hold off
```

Output is in Fig. 1.

### Code with histogram()

Some remarks

1. First check: a) `sum(f)` is `1` if `Nbins` adjusted with histogram()'s Normalization as probability, b) `sum(f)/N` is 1 if `Nbins` is manually set without normalization.
2. pdf requires the width of the bin (`dx`) in the graph `g`

Code

```
%%METHOD 5: with histogram()
% http://stackoverflow.com/a/38809232/54964
N=10000;

figure(4);
h = histogram(randn(N,1), 'Normalization', 'probability') % hist() deprecated!
Nbins=h.NumBins;
edges=h.BinEdges; 
x=zeros(1,Nbins);
f=h.Values;
for counter=1:Nbins
    midPointShift=abs(edges(counter)-edges(counter+1))/2; % same constant for all
    x(counter)=edges(counter)+midPointShift;
end
dx=diff(x(1:2)); % constast for all
g=1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-0.5*x.^2) .* dx; % pdf of ND
% Use if Nbins manually set
%new_area=sum(f)/N % diff of consecutive edges constant
% Use if histogarm() Normalization probability
new_area=sum(f)
% 1.0000
% No bar() needed here with histogram() Normalization probability
hold on;
plot(x,g,'r');hold off
```

Output in Fig. 2 and expected output is met: area 1.0000.

Matlab: 2016a
System: Linux Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Linux kernel 4.6

Comment: I am confused, why does the [MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html#buiynvy-14) say to use `pdf` instead of `probability` to have the bar areas sum to one? When you use `sum(h.values)` aren't you summing just the bin heights rather than the bin areas?

Comment: I had the same question as the OP and what confused me is that you are saying the exact opposite of MATLAB documentation. Please check https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html#input_argument_namevalue_Normalization

It clearly says to use `pdf` to have the bar areas sum to one and not `probability`. Moreover you are using `sum(f)` where `f=h.Values` to show that area is one. `h.Values` correspond to bin heights, so as per definition of `probability` normalization that will sum to one but that is not the same as bar areas.

Comment: "Code with histogram()":  If you multiply randn(N,1) by some constant, the red line will not match the data anymore.

Comment: I'm using @marsei answer. And when my histogram is not "very" normal, and I'm using a fitted spline to h.Value.

Comment: For non normal: [curve, goodness, output] = fit(x(:),h.Values(:),'smoothingspline','SmoothingParam',0.9999999);
lPlot = plot(x(:),curve(x));. For normal just look @marsei answer.

Comment: @Pedro77 Can you please edit this answer directoly to show where you would do the change?

Answer (score 1):

For some Distributions, Cauchy I think, I have found that trapz will overestimate the area, and so the pdf will change depending on the number of bins you select. In which case I do

```
[N,h]=hist(q_f./theta,30000); % there Is a large range but most of the bins will be empty
plot(h,N/(sum(N)*mean(diff(h))),'+r')
```

Comment: Hi! Is the quantity *mean(diff(h))* supposed to be the width of the bins?

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent three part guide for [Histogram Adjustments in MATLAB](http://maprabu.blogspot.com/2014/06/histogram-adjustments-in-matlab.html) ([broken original link](http://imageprocessingblog.com/histogram-adjustments-in-matlab-part-i/), [archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150225074528/http://imageprocessingblog.com/histogram-adjustments-in-matlab-part-i)), 
the first part is on Histogram Stretching.