# How to create 3D joint density plot MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, probability, histogram

I 'm having a problem with creating a joint density function from data. What I have is queue sizes from a stock as two vectors saved as:

```
X = [askQueueSize bidQueueSize];
```

I then use the hist3-function to create a 3D histogram. This is what I get:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/709705/hist-plot.png

What I want is to have the Z-axis normalized so that it goes from [0 1].

How do I do that? Or do someone have a great *joint density matlab* function on stock?

This is similar ([How to draw probability density function in MatLab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757387/how-to-draw-probability-density-function-in-matlab)) but in 2D.

What I want is 3D with `x:ask queue, y:bid queue, z:probability`.

Would greatly appreciate if someone could help me with this, because I've hit a wall over here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from a guy at mathworks forum, this is the great solution I ended up with:

(data_x and data_y are values, which you want to calculate at hist3)

```
x = min_x:step:max_x; % axis x, which you want to see
y = min_y:step:max_y; % axis y, which you want to see

[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y); *%important for "surf" - makes defined grid*

pdf = hist3([data_x , data_y],{x y}); %standard hist3 (calculated for yours axis)
pdf_normalize = (pdf'./length(data_x)); %normalization means devide it by length of 
                                         %data_x (or data_y)
figure()
surf(X,Y,pdf_normalize) % plot distribution
```

This gave me the joint density plot in 3D. Which can be checked by calculating the integral over the surface with:

```
integralOverDensityPlot = sum(trapz(pdf_normalize));
```

When the variable *step* goes to zero the variable *integralOverDensityPlot* goes to 1.0

Hope this help someone!

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't see a simple way of doing this. You can get the histogram counts back from hist3 using

```
[N C] = hist3(X);
```

and the idea would be to normalise them with:

```
N = N / sum(N(:));
```

but I can't find a nice way to plot them back to a histogram afterwards (You can use `bar3(N)`, but I think the axes labels will need to be set manually).

The solution I ended up with involves modifying the code of `hist3`. If you have access to this (`edit hist3`) then this may work for you, but I'm not really sure what the legal situation is (you need a licence for the statistics toolbox, if you copy hist3 and modify it yourself, this is probably not legal).

Anyway, I found the place where the data is being prepared for a `surf` plot. There are 3 matrices corresponding to x, y, and z. Just before the contents of the z matrix were calculated (line 256), I inserted:

```
n = n / sum(n(:));
```

which normalises the count matrix.

Finally once the histogram is plotted, you can set the axis limits with:

```
xlim([0, 1]);
```

if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fast way how to do this with hist3 function:

```
[bins centers] = hist3(X); % X should be matrix with two columns
c_1 = centers{1};
c_2 = centers{2};
pdf = bins / (sum(sum(bins))*(c_1(2)-c_1(1)) * (c_2(2)-c_2(1)));
```

If you "integrate" this you will get 1.

```
sum(sum(pdf * (c_1(2)-c_1(1)) * (c_2(2)-c_2(1))))
```