# Matlab Plotting Normal Distribution Probability Density Function

Tags: matlab, statistics, probability, normal-distribution, probability-density

I am new to statistics. I have a discriminant function:

g(x) = ln p(x| w)+ lnP(w)

I know it has a normal distribution. I know mü and sigma variables. How can I plot pdf function of it at Matlab?

Here is a conversation: [How to draw probability density function in MatLab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757387/how-to-draw-probability-density-function-in-matlab) however I don't want to use any toolbax of Matlab.

Comment: what do you mean by `toolbar of Matlab`?

Comment: and if you know the mean and std, then you have everything you need to create a formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

Comment: @Rasman I think he means tool*box*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [normpdf](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/normpdf.html), or [mvnpdf](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/mvnpdf.html) for a multivariate Normal distribution:

```
mu = 0;
sigma = 1;

xs = [-5:.1:5];
ys = normpdf(xs, mu, sigma);
clf;
plot(xs, ys);
```

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB plots vectors of data, so you'll need to make an X-vector, and a Y-vector.

If I had a function, say, x^2, i might do:

```
x = -1:.01:1; %make the x-vector
y = x.^2; %square x
plot(x,y);
```

You know the function of the PDF (y = exp(-x.^2./sigma^2).*1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2) ), so all you have to do is make the x-vector, and plot away!

Answer (score 0):

Based upon a comment from @kamaci, this question gives a complete answer using [@Pete's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13465719/8239061).

To avoid using a MATLAB toolbox, just plot the [Normal probability density function (PDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) directly.

```
mu = 12.5;      % mean
sigma = 3.75;   % standard deviation
fh=@(x) exp(-((x-mu).^2)./(2*(sigma^2)))*(1/sqrt(2*pi*(sigma^2)));  % PDF function
X = 0:.01:25;
p = plot(X,fh(X),'b-')
```

[image: PDF for Normal(12.5,3.75)]