# Create histogram normalizated and fitting it with a gamma distribution on Matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram

I know that I can fit a histogram with a gamma distribution in this way:

`histfit(data,bins-number,'gamma');figure(gcf);`

And I know too that I can normalize a histogram with histnorm. But how can I create a normalized gamma distribution with its histogram?

Any idea or suggestion? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

#### EDIT:

In response to BruceWarrior's comment below, `histfit` will normalize the data for you... just replace `x` with your data. If you want to know how to normalize a histogram yourself such that it is a probability density, [see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320677/how-to-normalize-a-histogram-in-matlab/5321546#5321546) to that very question. Note that the accepted answer will not give you a probability density (i.e., the area under the curve will not be 1).

---

You can use the [`gamrnd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/gamrnd.html) function to generate random variables with a Gamma distribution for a given shape parameter `a` and scale parameter `b`. You can then call [`histfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/histfit.html) on this data to fit the Gamma distribution to the normalized histogram. Here's an example:

```
x=gamrnd(1,2,1000,1);
histfit(x,50,'gamma')
```

#### a=1,b=2

[image]

#### a=2, b=2

[image]

Comment: But I have a real data, I don't want generate one with random number following a gamma distribution. I want normalizate (i mean, with summations of all probabilities equal to one), with my array of data and after create a histogram with this distribution normalizated and after make the fitting

Comment: @BruceWarrior: Please see my edit above. I've added a link to an answer showing how to normalize a histogram.