# Bayes classification in matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, bayesian

I have 50 images and created a database of the green channel of each image by separating them into two classes (Skin and wound) and storing the their respective green channel value.

Also, I have 1600 wound pixel values and 3000 skin pixel values.

Now I have to use bayes classification in matlab to classify the skin and wound pixels in a new (test) image using the data base that I have. I have tried the in-built command `diaglinear` but results are poor resulting in lot of misclassification.

Also, I dont know if it's a normal distribution or not so can't use gaussian estimation for finding the conditional probability density function for the data.

Is there any way to perform pixel wise classification?

If there is any part of the question that is unclear, please ask.

I'm looking for help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, it would be great if you could provide examples of your images. Why did you choose the green channel ? I'm not sure what you mean by pixel wise classification, but usually in image classification you try to make sense from the image as a whole. You could try Fourier Transform and see how different your images are in the frequency domain. Anyway, feature extraction would be your first step.

Comment: A commonly used technique for image segmentation are markov random fields. If you google it, there are a lot of good papers.

Comment: If you want to classify a single pixel as wound or skin, it will depend on all the pixels around it right? I would think SVM with an appropriate kernel over the neighbourhood of each pixel could do the job.

Comment: Look, you need to tell us more about the problem if you want help. What sort of algorithm do you think the computer needs to do, to classify the pixels? To be explicit, one needs some idea of what kind of image statistics the status of a pixel might depend on!

Comment: Thanks sanjay for ur suggestion but, my dataset is not very large to be able to use the SVM classifier so i would stick to the method propose by santonsh... any further help would be acknoledged...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you realy want to use pixel wise classification (quite simple, but why not?) try exploring pixel value distributions with hist()/imhist(). It might give you a clue about a gaussianity...
Second, you might fit your values to the some appropriate curves (gaussians?) manually with fit() if you have curve fitting toolbox (or again do it manualy). Then multiply the curves by probabilities of the wound/skin if you like it to be MAP classifier, and finally find their intersection. Voela! you have your descition value V. 
if Xi skin
else -> wound

Comment: Thanks a lot for understanding my problem in the right way... I exactly want to do what is said but now i am having problem with the fit option . i have curve fitting tool box. It would be of great help if u can help me with a brief code or example..I u need any other info let me know..

Comment: Hiii santonsh, how i approached the problem as u suggested ... was i took the histogram of my data, normalised it, this gives me the pdf but the problem is how to fit a curve over the normalised histogram (obtained by using the method as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320677/how-to-normalize-a-histogram-in-matlab). I have the prior and need to do exactly the way u mentioned .....can u please explain it hw to do a bit more, as i being new to matlab am unaware even with simple functions...