# How to plot probability density functions in matlab?

Tags: matlab, distribution, uniform

I need to plot a probability density function of a uniformly distributed matrix from

```
U = rand (1,1000)
```

but I can't use the ksdensity function. I've tried this:

```
term = 1000;
U = rand (1,term);
x=0:0.001:1;
for j = 2:term;
    u_height(j) = u_height(j-1)+((abs(x(j)-U(j))<0.01/2)/0.01)/term;
    n_height(j) = n_height(j-1)+((abs(x(j)-N(j))<0.01/2)/0.01)/term;
end
```

but it's not plotting correctly

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What's wrong with `plot(U/sum(U))`?

Comment: Have you considered a histogram? see `hist` and `histc`.

Comment: @Junuxx, That will not work, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320677/how-to-normalize-a-histogram-in-matlab

Comment: @slayton: I see your point, thanks for the correction. Still, OPs method seems convoluted.

Comment: @Junuxx, yea the method doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

The function `ksdensity` should work fine. You need to specify that that the range of the PDF is finite, and use a box kernel.

```
u = rand(10000,1);

ksdensity(u, 'Support', [0 1], 'kernel', 'box');
```

Additionally you can approximate the pdf using `histc`

```
u = rand(10000,1);
bins = 0:.05:1;
counts = hist(u, bins);
p = counts ./ trapz(bins, counts);

plot(bins, p);
```

Comment: Why do you recommend `box`? (opposed to keeping the default setting or using `epanechnikov`)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin both are fine actually, but after messing around with the various options I felt that a box kernel produced an estimate that more closely resembled a uniform distribution.

Comment: while this is close to what I was looking for, it's not precise enough, even with a 10,000 size vector.

Comment: @user2064077  remember that this is an estimate of the underlying distribution. The precision is going to depend on the data set size and quality.