# normalize 2 histogram and plot

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, normal-distribution

I'm new in matlab and i tried to normalize two normal distributions according to [How to normalize a histogram in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320677/how-to-normalize-a-histogram-in-matlab), but i couldn't. Can someone tell me how to normalize the two normal distribution below:

```
[f,x]=hist(normrnd(25,2.5),50);%# create histogram from a normal distribution.
g=1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-0.5*x.^2);%# pdf of the normal distribution

figure(1)
bar(x,f/trapz(x,f));hold on
plot(x,g,'r');hold off
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "you couldn't?"  What exactly is wrong, and what problems are you encountering?  We're here to solve problems, not guess at to what reasons your code may be wrong.

Comment: Sorry. I used this code:

`[f,x]=hist(normrnd(25,2.5),50);%# create histogram from a normal distribution.
g=1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-0.5*x.^2);%# pdf of the normal distribution

figure(1)
bar(x,f/trapz(x,f));hold on
plot(x,g,'r');hold off`

But it gives me a strange thing. I dont know waht i am doing wrong.

Comment: Please update your post with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. Use randn instead of normrnd.
2. Increase the number of numbers you are trying to generate.

Code:

```
[f,x]=hist(randn(10000,2.5),50);%# create histogram from a normal distribution.
g=1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-0.5*x.^2);%# pdf of the normal distribution

figure(1)
bar(x,f/trapz(x,f));hold on
plot(x,g,'r');hold off
```

Comment: But i have a defined normal distribution, with mean equal to 25 and a standard deviation equal to 2.5.