# How to find PDF from sample set in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics, probability, sample-data, probability-density

I have some observations from an unknown source. This set of observations is x, for example :

```
x = [97 , 102.3, 95.05 , 89.1 , 117 , ...]; % this is just an example. data set could contain any thing.
```

provided x is large enough, I should be able to say something about the probability distribution function, right?

So how can I do this in MATLAB so I can get `p(x = 101)` or `p(x = 5)` ? the first one will probably be very high.

Any kind of assumption (normal distribution etc.) is ok, I just want a simple answer for probabilities. And maybe I don't have to explicitly know the PDF, I just need a way to implement `p(x = x_star)`, where x_star is not necessarily a member of x. How can I do this?

Thanks for any help !

### My Attempts

The simplest attempt is `length(find(x==x_star))/length(x)`, however this returns zero if for example there is no `101` in the observations. However looking at the distribution it should be a high probability.

### Edit :

My function according to Kamtal's answer :

```
function p = get_probability_from_sample_set(S, X)
% finds the probability that a sample from S is equal to X
[mu,sigma] = normfit(S);
 z = 1:200;
 xfit = normpdf(z,mu,sigma);
 p = xfit(find(z == X)); 
end
```

`p` returns `[]`. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are your values all integer?

Comment: Check [`hist`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html)

Comment: @Kamtal no they are floats. Luis Mendo, ok, then how do I get the probability from the histogram?

Comment: @halilpazarlama Check for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320677/how-to-normalize-a-histogram-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

```
 x = randi(200,[1000 1]);
 [mu,sigma] = normfit(x);
 z = 1:200;
 xfit = normpdf(z,mu,sigma);
 p = xfit(find(z == round(X)));
```

If your values are in `[0 0.1]`,

```
 x = randi(1000,[1000 1])/10000;
 [mu,sigma] = normfit(x);
 z = 0:1e-5:0.1;
 xfit = normpdf(z,mu,sigma);
 nearestToz = z(abs(z - X) == min(abs(z - X)));
 p = xfit(find(z == nearestToz));
```

Comment: Thanks ! This looks right, but does this assume integer values? Because it was just an example, my actual values are floats, and they change from order of 1e-3 to 1e3. Will this work for all types of x and x_star ?

Comment: @halilpazarlama, Since `z = 1:200;` it will give integers, if you change `z = 1:stepsize:200;` you could have access to floats, depending on your data.

Comment: Oh so it should be `z = min(S):stepsize:max(S)` ? Please see the edit to the question.

Comment: @halilpazarlama, yes. you can plot `xfit` to see the pdf.

Comment: Ok so does `p = xfit(..)` make sense? Or how do I get the probability?

Comment: @halilpazarlama, `p=xfit(find(z == x_star))`,  and try `z=unique(x);`, I think that is more efficient.

Comment: Ok but this still gives zero for queries that are not in the sample set, right?

Comment: @halilpazarlama, I forgot that you want probabilities for data that aren't in set. you have to use `z = min(S):stepsize:max(S)` with a small step to cover all the values you want their probability.

Comment: Ok thanks. This works if query is in z. But still not for all values, except stepsize goes to zero (which fails the memory). I still think that there should be a way that works for **every** query.

Comment: @halilpazarlama, Do you have your queries in an array? so we could somehow insert them all in `z`, or they are random?

Comment: No, they are not pre-determined. I want to make a system that gives a probability for any given query. So we can say that the query set is the set of real numbers. **edit** : Maybe we can use the "closest" member of z.

Comment: @halilpazarlama, you could also use `p = xfit(find(z == round(X));`. They will almost be the same anyway.

Comment: no, neither the query set nor the data set is limited to integers.

Comment: @halilpazarlama, Ok that is the reason to use `round`. What would be the problem?

Comment: Hmm. What if my data set is between 0 and 0.1?