# Plot not extending to the complete height of my data

Tags: matlab, octave, probability-density, bernoulli-probability

I am attemtping to write a function that produces *m* random simulations of 5 Bernoulli Trials. I create a histogram showing the distribution of the number of successes across the *m* simulations.

I then need to also plot a line showing the theoretical / normalised distribution around the theoretical mean number of successes.

Here is my function as of now:

```
function x = generate_binomial_bernoulli(n,p,m)
  % generate Bi(n, p) outcomes m times

  emperical = zeros(1,m);             % allocate array for m simulations
  for i = 1:m                         % iterate over m simulations
    successes = 0;                    % count the number of successful trials per simualtion (0-5)
    for j = 1:n                       % iterate through the n trials
      u = rand;                       % generate random nuumber from 0-1
      if (u <= p)                     % if random number is <= p
        successes++;                  % count it as a success
      endif
    end
    emperical(i) = successes;         % store the number of successful trials in this simulation
  end

  close all;                          % close any existing graphs

  x_values = [0:n];                   % array of x-axis values        
  hist(emperical, x_values, "facecolor", "r"); % plot empirical data
  xlim([-0.5 (n + 0.5)]);             % set x-axis to allow for histogram bar widths

  hold on;                            % hold current graph

  mean = n * p;                       % theoretical mean
  norm = normpdf(x_values, mean, 1);  % normalised y values
  plot(x_values, norm, "color", "b"); % plot theoretical distribution

  legend('Emprical', 'Theoretical');   

end
```

When the function is called as

```
generate_binomial_bernoulli(5, 0.2, 100)
```

I expect to see a red histogram showing the results of 100 simulations (emperical results), and then a blue line plot normalised around the mean of 1 success (theoretical result).

Here is the graph produced:

[image]

The emperical results are displayed correctly, but the theoretical plot is only extending to the height of a very low value on the y-axis.

Where is my function going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

"normpdf" is a probability density function. So it is "normal" that you see numbers below 1. However, histogram returns the frequency of your numbers, it is not a probability. Maybe you want to normalize your frequencies and treat them as probabilities.

```
freqs=hist(emperical, x_values, 'facecolor', 'r'); % plot empirical data
freqs=freqs/sum(freqs);
figure; bar(x_values,freqs)
```

Comment: WIth the line `freqs=hist(emperical, x_values, 'facecolor', 'r');`, I am getting an empty grpah - if you assign the histogram to a variable, does it not actually get displayed? Do I first have to call `hist(emperical, x_values, 'facecolor', 'r');`, followed by `freqs=hist(emperical, x_values, 'facecolor', 'r');`?

Comment: You only get the frequencies, not plotting. Try histogram(emperical, x_values, 'Normalization','pdf'); 
 Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34405518/7659682

Comment: As you stated that `normpdf` returns a probability, I have changed the plotting line to `plot(x_values, theoretical * m, "color", "b");` and it works perfectly, but is this bad practice?

Comment: As you multiply it by something, it will exceed 1 and it is not a pdf anymore. I would rather normalize the histogram, your choice.

Comment: Yes, the question you posted seems a lot more suitable, however I am actually using Octave and not MATLAB, and the property 'Normalization' isn't defined for the `hist` function in Octave. I will see if I can find the Octave equivalent.